# Drop rows which has a list as value in one of the columns

Tags: r, list, subset

Recently I've been extracting data from NCBI data base.
That's how my data is structured

```
 ID             subtype          subname                               
   <chr>          <chr>            <chr>                                 
 1 AKBV01000001.1 strain           K-12                                  
 2 AKBV01000001.1 sub_strain       MG1655                                
 3 AKVX01000001.1 strain           K-12                                  
 4 AKVX01000001.1 sub_strain       MG1655                                
 5 AP019675.1     strain           GSH8M-2                               
 6 AP019675.1     country          Japan:Tokyo                           
 7 AP019675.1     isolation_source wastewater treatment plant effluent   
 8 AP019675.1     lat_lon          35.6316 N 139.7460 E                  
 9 AP019675.1     collection_date  2018-08                               
10 AP019675.1     note             O184:H40 (in silico prediction);~ST542
```

For further analysis I had to use `pivot_wider()`

```
bacteria_dataset <- lasting_tib_treated %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = subtype,
              values_from = subname)
```

After using this a Warning comes out telling that my tibble will have lists on the values of the columns as follows

```
   <chr> <list>  <list>      <list>      <list>          
 1 Bac_1 <chr ~ <chr [1]>  <chr [1]>  <chr [2]>          
 2 Bac_2 <chr ~ <chr [1]>  <chr [1]>  <chr [1]>   
 3 Bac_3 <chr ~ <chr [1]>  <chr [1]>  <chr [1]>
```

I wanted to drop these lists from my dataset. So i triyed this

```
bacteria_dataset_treated <- bacteria_dataset

for (i in 1:length(bacteria_dataset)){
  
  
  for (a in 1:length(bacteria_dataset[1,])){
    
   bacteria_dataset_treated <- bacteria_dataset_treated[!(bacteria_dataset_treated[i,a] %>% 
                                                             length() >= 2),]
  }
}
```

That's not working and I imagine that must be a simpler solution, but I'm new here I couldn't find it yet

Comment: I think you have some duplicates.  Create a sequence column and it should work without creating the `list` i.e. `lasting_tib_treated %>% mutate(rn = data.table::rowid(subtype)) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = subtype,
              values_from = subname)`

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` for testing

Comment: So... I'm new in these things, sometimes I can't explain, but I will try. Subtype are the variables and subnames are the values, then sometimes the same bacteria repeats for 4 times but with 4 different subtypes. Maybe within one one theses bacteria the subtype repeats, then the two values would be grouped in a list

Comment: Yes, I understand.  The issue with showing only the error or ouput is that we can't test how you got that.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I've edited my comment, see if it's clear.

Comment: It's okay.  My comment was based on how you are getting the `list` output after pivot_wider.  To investigate further, a a small example that shows the issue would be great

Comment: To be honest I'm more interested in eliminating these rows, checking closely these data are not interesting to me, some of these lists shows to hosts, for example and must have only one

Comment: I will try to do the SRE!

Comment: Yes, I do understand your point.  My only request is that without an example, we may be doing trial and error testing and it may take a bit of time to get to the exact issue.

Comment: I've tried to show how's my data is structured, I'm afraind I do not know how to generate a dput for testing

Comment: With that example, I am not getting any list.  It could be that there is no duplicates for that example

Comment: Can you try `lasting_tib_treated %>%   mutate(rn = rowid(ID, subtype)) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = subtype, values_from = subname)`.  This will make sure that you won't get that list columns